# Gunicorn sync worker and threads

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am running a Gunicorn server with 2 'sync' workers.
When i run `htop --filter gunicorn`, i get 2 worker entries as expected.

But, when i press `H` to show number of threads, it shows a lot of entries.
I am running in hyper-threading enabled cpu with 8 physical cores.

**Why are there so many entries after pressing `H`?
Ideally a *sync worker only has single thread*, so should there be 2 threads only.** 
Am i missing something? Please help me resolve this confusion

[image: htop] 
[image: htop -H] 
[image: pstree -p]

Comment: what's your number `--threads` in your config gunicorn. a `Sync` worker handles a single request at a time not a single thread.

Comment: @TanThien i have no such setting. `--threads` makes it `gthread` worker, right? I am concernec with sync workers only

Comment: yes with no setting `--threads`, worker run without switch to `gthread`.  Your multithreading can become your django app, django is multithreaded by `nothreading` default.